Facing 500 error while upgrading java 11 to java 17
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed:
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiSP.isIMS()'] with root cause","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].
[dispatcherServlet]","level":"ERROR","stack_trace":"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiSP.isIMS()

I'm facing the above error in my local machine, while upgrading java 11 from java 17, any idea how can I fix this.
I have tried to add some mq dependency in POM file and changed some MQ method also
